# how to check if dataset contains specific value in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, select, datagridview, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset that contains multiple values. I want to take those rows from that dataset that contains "the specific value" and firstly I want to display those in a MessageBox.
Furtheron, I try to view them in a datagridview called ErrorsDgV.

I already searched this topic and found a good function,  but unfortunately, all I get from the MessageBox is an empty box.

```
ErrorsDgV.DataSource = Srchdataset.Tables("blubb")
LineLabel.Text = "Lines: " & 
Srchdataset.Tables("blubb").Rows.Count.ToString
ErrorsDgV.Sort(ErrorsDgV.Columns(1), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
ErrorsDgV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
ErrorsDgV.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"

Dim answer As String = ""
Dim SearchRows() As Data.DataRow
SearchRows = Srchdataset.Tables("blubb").Select("Data = 'the specific value'")
answer = ""

For k As Integer = 0 To SearchRows.Length - 1
    If answer = "" Then
        answer = SearchRows(k).Item("Data")
    Else
        answer = answer & vbNewLine & SearchRows(k).Item("Data")
    End If
Next
MsgBox(" " & answer)
```

I debugged also and got to know that SearchRows is empty, even if the specific value is inlcuded in that DataSet.

Comment: Why don't you let the server find your records? That is a lot faster than downloading the content of the table onto the client and then starting to filter it. If "contains" means somewhere in the text there is this value, then the ```LIKE```-operator should be used, e.g. ```Data LIKE '%the specific value%'```...

Comment: Do you see the value you are searching in the data grid view?

Comment: No, I used `answer = String.Join("", SearchRows(k).ItemArray())`  in the for loop for the if and else statement and used `answer` as a datasource for my datagridview. But nothing happens. When I use answer in a messagebox then I see the values that I want to see.